# About the intelligent code completion problem of vscode + vue + ts

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-code, volar

As shown in the figure below, a `color` prop is defined in the component and the type is marked. When the component is referenced elsewhere, vscode cannot intelligently prompt the value of this property, it can only be typed by hand. When typing a letter `r` in the figure below, shouldn’t it prompt `red`? Please advise how to set vscode to have intelligent code completion prompts. The Volar plugin has been installed, what configuration needs to be done?
[image: image here]

The ts version of Volar has been installed and takeover mode has been enabled.